# Spring Data Rest Repository won't expose delete

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I have a Repository for a User object and I'm trying to expose delete by copying the signature from the CRUD repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, String>{
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    User findOne(String username);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USERS_READ')")
    List<User> findAll();

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USERS_WRITE')")
    User save(User user);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USERS_WRITE')")
    void delete(String username);

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USERS_WRITE')")
    void delete(User user);
}
```

Saving a user works fine:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/users 
Request Method:POST
Status Code:201 Created
```

But when I try to delete a user I get http 405 error which from what I understand means the delete method isn't being exposed:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/users/testUser3
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
```

When I do a delete call using a CrudRepository it works.
Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 4):

I found the cause: 
T findOne(ID id) and void delete(ID id) are somehow connected.
When I removed the @RestResource(exported = false) annotation from findOne, delete started working.
Seems like a bug to me, or undocumented behavior.

I didn't expose findOne because my server was using it for authentication so I couldn't annotate it with @PreAuthorize. 
What I ended up doing is adding a separate method for the server:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USERS_READ')")
User findOne(String username);

@RestResource(exported = false)
User getUserByUsername(String username);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

have same problem, looking into source code `DefaultExposureAwareCrudMethods`:

```
this.exposesDelete = Lazy.of(() -> exposes(crudMethods.getDeleteMethod()) && crudMethods.hasFindOneMethod());
```

so really, delete() and findOne() are connected it the sense, that delete is not considered exposed, when a find method is not exposed, like findById(ID). I also had to add @Modifying to the deleteById(ID) method, maybe a bug?